# Cucumber execute java

Tags: java, cucumber

MAC OS And Maven project

In my code

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "cucumber /Users/jinsoohan/Documents/projects/jira-rest-api/features/");
```

Throws an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 
Cannot run program "cucumber": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: can you run the command from cmd/terminal?

Comment: Sounds like `cucumber` is not in your PATH. Do you need to provide an absolute path to the binary? e.g. `/foo/bar/bin/cucumber`?

Comment: I try /Users/jinsoohan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/cucumber but it's not working.

Comment: I can run cucumber in terminal